# LINQ query to evaluate in C# before translating to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

This works

```
DateTime dtYesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
data = data.Where(d => d.CreatedTime <= dtYesterday);
```

But this doesn't

```
data = data.Where(d => d.CreatedTime <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
```

because EF cannot translate it into SQL. That's fine.

But just out of curiosity, is there a way to force it to evaluate the value of `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` before translating it to SQL?

I'm wondering if there is a syntax similar to this?

```
data = data.Where(d => d.CreatedTime <= ForceEvaluate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)));
```

Comment: It all depends on the `IQueryProvider` that the `IQueryable` exposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` is that the former preserves the expression the programmer (i.e. you) wrote to present it to the query engine that performs the query (i.e. the RDBMS). Figuring out that `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` is a function that needs to be evaluated would work, but that is too much magic compared to a simple and straightforward solution with familiar and easily recognizable syntax:

```
DateTime dtYesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
data = data.Where(d => d.CreatedTime <= dtYesterday);
```

Having to guess would rob programmers of the opportunity to pass functions such as `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` to the RDBMS: it is entirely conceivable that the current database date/time is different from your application server, potentially resulting in a different set of rows. On the other hand, introducing the `ForceEvaluate` syntax would be pointless, because if you must mark the expression to be evaluated, you might as well do it using the familiar way (see your code that I pasted above).